# Parsing large database file

Tags: database, rust

I'm creating a database system in Rust. I want to read through database files and select rows based on criteria: `UPDATE table SET a=b WHERE c=d`. How do PostgreSQL or MySQL find rows in some milliseconds considering column `c` is not indexed?

I want to use `BufReader` to not have to open the whole file because it will overflow memory but can't find crates or methods to implement this.

Comment: Have you timed your code vs. an RDBMS' execution of the same query on the same dataset? I'm not sure but I would guess if you are seeing your code runs an order of magnitude slower, it is because the RDBMS can parallelize the query even without an index. I think this would be called a parallel sequential scan. You might be able to call "EXPLAIN ANALYZE <your query>" to confirm.

Comment: @C-RAD thanks so i look into this "parallel sequential scan" and I implemented it by spawning a thread for each chunk of 250 lines.  It really increased the performance but it still takes ~7 sec to read a 700 mb file.

Comment: My immediate thought is that Postgres (and probably other dbs) use Multiprocessing, not Multithreading. They have worker processes waiting to do work, so they avoid the start up cost. You might try a multiprocessing approach, or a threadpool approach, where you have threads started and waiting to do the work. The Rust book has a good threadpool example in chapter 20. You might also consider asking this question on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ or https://users.rust-lang.org/